# Type hint to return an instance of a class, where typevar is the class type

Tags: python

How to write the return type hints to indicate that the function returns an instance of class "Class_" ?

```
Class_ = TypeVar("Class_", bound=type)

def make_class(class_: Class_) -> Class_:
    return class_()
```

Comment: Why not do it the other way around, the output is `T` and the input is `type[T]` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to use `Type` from `typing`. This is the generic implementation of what you are trying to define with `TypeVar("Class_", bound=type)`.

So all you need to do is provide a generic variable to represent an instance of the class returned, and then you can use the generic `Type` to specify the input argument.

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T")


def make_class(class_: Type[T]) -> T:
    return class_()
```